# Windows has started encrypting all my newly created files and folders by default

Tags: windows, encryption

For some reason, **all my new files and folders are getting encrypted**.

**I am able to access them** but when I right-click on the folder or file and go to properties>general>advanced>compress or encrypt attributes, the contents are encrypted by default.

[Encrypted box is checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBfHO.png)

Is there anything I can do to make it **unencrypted by default**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when the parent directory was encrypted with the option to "Apply changes to this folder, subfolders, and files". This is the default option.

[image: Windows EFS options]

Not only does this encrypt existing files and subfolders in that directory, but it will also cause any new files or subfolders you create in it to be encrypted by default.

**To fix this**, remove the encryption on the parent directory under its advanced attributes. If you want the parent directory encrypted, re-encrypt it but change the option to "Apply changes to this folder only".